# Set file modification date from date stored as filename

Tags: awk, files, find, date, touch

I have a lot of files where filename contains file creation date (`IMG_YYYYMMDD_hhmmss.jpg`):

```
IMG_20171015_133516.jpg
IMG_20171015_133827.jpg
IMG_20171015_142634.jpg
IMG_20171015_142834.jpg
IMG_20171015_142857.jpg
```

but actual file creation date is different. I need to set it back to date from a filename.

I know how to change the date of all files to current date:

```
find -type f -exec touch {} \;
```

and how to parse the file name to get the date in the proper format for `touch -t`

```
echo IMG_20171015_133516.jpg | awk -F_ '{print $2 substr($3,0,4) "." substr($3,5,2)}'
201710151335.16
```

But I have no idea how to combine these commands together to change all files.

```
find -type f -exec touch -t"$(echo '{}' | awk -F_ '{print $2 substr($3,0,4) "." substr($3,5,2)}')" {} \;
```

returns

> touch: invalid date format ‘.’

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the shell:

```
for f in ./IMG_*.jpg ; do 
    t=${f##*/} 
    touch "$f" -t "${t:4:8}${t:13:4}.${t:17:2}"
done
```

Bash, ksh, zsh etc have the `${var:n:m}` substring expansion, and if you need to do it recursively, enable `globstar` and use `**/IMG_*.jpg` instead.

Doing it with `find` needs the shell, too:

```
$ find -name "IMG_*.jpg" -exec bash -c '
  for f; do t=${f##*/}; touch "$f" -t "${t:4:8}${t:13:4}.${t:17:2}" ; done
  ' sh {} \+
```

The first argument to Bash after the script goes to the `$0` variable, which usually contains the shell name. The rest go to the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc. and `for f` or `for f in "$@"` loops over them.
The construct is here is rather common (at least in unix.SE answers).
The main part of the loop here is the same as in the first example.

---

The `find` command in your question `find .. -exec touch -t"$(...)" {} \;` doesn't work since the command substitution is in double quotes, so it gets expanded before `find` runs. The `{}` is piped literally to `awk`, and it just so happens that the `awk` script only prints a dot.

If you did put the command substitution in *single* quotes, it would be passed to `touch` as-is (`find` would only substitute `{}`). `touch` would get the argument `-t$(echo ...)`, dollar signs, parenthesis and all. `find` doesn't run the command through the shell by itself, we need to explicitly do it, as above.

In single quotes example:

```
$ find -name x -exec echo 'hello $(foo {})' \;
hello $(foo ./x)
```

Comment: Works great, but I still don't know what's wrong with my approach. Why "$()" returns `.` instead formatted date?

Comment: @mx0, ah good point, perhaps that should have been elaborated. edited.